# Adding an ng-click event inside a filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I'm fairly new to Angular but I've been using it the past few weeks and have managed to work out most of the problems I've come across. This one however has me stumped.

I have an app that pulls in tweets from Twitter then - using an angular filter - pulls out all the urls and styles them as links. This part works fine but the client decided that links from Twitter were't safe so they wanted a disclaimer to fire every time a link was clicked. Simple enough - I hijacked the link and swapped the `href` for an `ng-click="openLink('url')"`. This is where the problem occurred - the `ng-click` doesn't work.

I'm pretty sure the problem has something to do with `$compile()` - I've had similar issues before - but I have no idea when or where to call it.

I've created a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/VQwBwl?p=preview) that is a lite version of what I'm after. The link at the top isn't loaded in dynamically and fires the `alertUrl()` function fine, but all the links generated by the filter fail.

I'm probably missing something really simple but it's been bugging me a while now so any help will be massively appreciated.

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: Will the links always be shown towards the end?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well you are correct that the html\content that you emit needs to be compiled for angularjs to resolve the alert function.

I have changed your plunker, and inject a compile directive (from [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile))

See it in action [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/vUWro6?p=preview)

The basic idea here is to compile the content produced from twitter feed dynamically.

```
<p compile="tweet.text | convertLinks"></p>
```

Comment: The Link to the directive no longer exists.