# angular ng-bind-html and directive within it

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

[Plunker Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/EZuKFBrE94bujWpcNat2?p=preview)

I have a element which I would like to bind html to it.

`<div ng-bind-html="details" upper></div>`

That works. Now, along with it I also have a directive which is bound to the bound html:

`$scope.details = 'Success! <a href="#/details/12" upper>details</a>'`

But the directive `upper` with the div and anchor do not evaluate. How do I make it work?

Comment: Look at my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17343696/adding-an-ng-click-event-inside-a-filter/17344875#17344875

Comment: @Chandermani not exactly using directive inside ng-bind-html-unsafe but using filter. But it will do, I just created a filter and passed to the directive. Thanks!

Comment: @SamSerious are you able to show how you did what you did for the filters?

Comment: the above solutions don't handle multiple changes of the value a
better solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/25516311/3343425

Answer (score 188, accepted):

I was also facing this problem and after hours searching the internet I read @Chandermani's comment, which proved to be the solution.
You need to call a 'compile' directive with this pattern:

### HTML:

```
<div compile="details"></div>
```

### JS:

```
.directive('compile', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(
            function(scope) {
                // watch the 'compile' expression for changes
                return scope.$eval(attrs.compile);
            },
            function(value) {
                // when the 'compile' expression changes
                // assign it into the current DOM
                element.html(value);

                // compile the new DOM and link it to the current
                // scope.
                // NOTE: we only compile .childNodes so that
                // we don't get into infinite loop compiling ourselves
                $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            }
        );
    };
}])
```

You can see a working [fiddle of it here](http://jsfiddle.net/NWZZE/6/)

Comment: In line #2, ie. `function(scope, element, attrs)`, where did you get from those three arguments, _scope_, _element_ and _attrs_?

Comment: @spaffy - they're part of Angular framework's signature for the `link` property.  They'll be passed automatically each time when `link` is called by the Angular framework.  They'll always be available.

Comment: Well done. You saved me those same hours of searching. I'm pulling content from SharePoint view REST API, which itself contains Angular markup such as ng-repeat. Your directive made it all work. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your directive it fixed the problems I was having. Now the angular code gets compiled but too many times. A ng-repeat with 3 object turns into the same values just 3x each. Whats going wrong here?

Comment: If you have been using `$sce.trustAsHtml` from another function to create the HTML that will be "compiled" with this directive, you should remove it. Thanks to @apoplexy

Answer (score 36):

Thanks for the great answer vkammerer. One optimization I would recommend is un-watching after the compilation runs once. The $eval within the watch expression could have performance implications.

```
    angular.module('vkApp')
  .directive('compile', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
      return function(scope, element, attrs) {
          var ensureCompileRunsOnce = scope.$watch(
            function(scope) {
               // watch the 'compile' expression for changes
              return scope.$eval(attrs.compile);
            },
            function(value) {
              // when the 'compile' expression changes
              // assign it into the current DOM
              element.html(value);

              // compile the new DOM and link it to the current
              // scope.
              // NOTE: we only compile .childNodes so that
              // we don't get into infinite loop compiling ourselves
              $compile(element.contents())(scope);

              // Use un-watch feature to ensure compilation happens only once.
              ensureCompileRunsOnce();
            }
        );
    };
}]);
```

[Here's a forked and updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/iambrandonm/yhZ77/1/)

Comment: Can i have the vice versa for it?

Comment: this is not work in response of ajax but accepted answer work

Comment: Warning: The fiddle for this answer works, but the `.directive()` code in the code posted in the answer does not.

Comment: this one worked for me. the chosen answer would trigger "Error: $rootScope:infdig
Infinite $digest Loop"

Comment: You shouldn't need the explict `$eval` - you can just use `attrs.compile` directly in place of the watched anonymous function. If you just provide a string expression, angular will call `$eval` on it anyway.

Answer (score 28):

Add this directive [angular-bind-html-compile](https://github.com/incuna/angular-bind-html-compile/blob/master/angular-bind-html-compile.js)

```js
.directive('bindHtmlCompile', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(function () {
        return scope.$eval(attrs.bindHtmlCompile);
      }, function (value) {
        // Incase value is a TrustedValueHolderType, sometimes it
        // needs to be explicitly called into a string in order to
        // get the HTML string.
        element.html(value && value.toString());
        // If scope is provided use it, otherwise use parent scope
        var compileScope = scope;
        if (attrs.bindHtmlScope) {
          compileScope = scope.$eval(attrs.bindHtmlScope);
        }
        $compile(element.contents())(compileScope);
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

Use it like this :

```
<div bind-html-compile="data.content"></div>
```

Really easy :)

Comment: Be careful, if you pass something like this: "$scope.loadContent = function() {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(require('html/main-content.html'));
    };" to it you can get infinite digest loop. Without the trustAsHtml it works.

Comment: I tried this option. Works like a charm! I also use $sce.trustAsHtml before passing it to the directive. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to comment.

I could not get this to work for ages. I modified my `ng-bind-html` code to use this custom directive, but I failed to remove the `$scope.html = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.html)` that was required for ng-bind-html to work. As soon as I removed this, the compile function started to work.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone dealing with content that has already been run through `$sce.trustAsHtml` here is what I had to do differently

```
function(scope, element, attrs) {
    var ensureCompileRunsOnce = scope.$watch(function(scope) {
            return $sce.parseAsHtml(attrs.compile)(scope);
        },
        function(value) {
            // when the parsed expression changes assign it into the current DOM
            element.html(value);

            // compile the new DOM and link it to the current scope.
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);

            // Use un-watch feature to ensure compilation happens only once.
            ensureCompileRunsOnce();
        });
}
```

*This is only the `link` portion of the directive as I'm using a different layout. You will need to inject the `$sce` service as well as `$compile`.*

Answer (score -2):

Best solution what I've found! I copied it and it work's exactly as I needed. Thanks, thanks, thanks ...

in directive link function I have

```
app.directive('element',function($compile){
  .
  .
     var addXml = function(){
     var el = $compile('<xml-definitions definitions="definitions" />')($scope);
     $scope.renderingElement = el.html();
     }
  .
  .
```

and in directive template:

```
<span compile="renderingElement"></span>
```