# Dynamic tab content and params

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to build a set of dynamic tabsets with dynamic content,

http://plnkr.co/edit/bhtMin1B1dwwqYvyrpVl?p=preview

1) Clicking on Dashboard opens a new tab with directive

- When I provide the content of a as the directive, this gets rendered as a string.
- I've tried to use the html bind unsafe and $compile functions to make this run as an Angular component - but haven't be able to

2) Click on menu [Project Management-> Project] shows a list of Sites, on clicking of which I need to open another tab passing a parameter (Proj-ID or Site-Id)

- The idea is to call a function on click of the Site Name, I'll open a new tab with content as a directive
- But since I am stuck with the previous problem, I am not able to do this
- Is this the right way of passing params to the directive.

Right now, the plunkr tries to o/p the tab content as a file, a string and compile - with no success

[I've revised this question with relevant details from a prev question]

**SOLUTION FOUND FOR #1:**

For some reason ng-bind-html-unsafe doesn't work with Angular Elements.
I had to do create a compile directive http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile, based on info I found here on STO

Answer (score 0):

In tabs-directive.html, you can definitely use [ngBindHtmlUnsafe](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive%3angBindHtmlUnsafe). Make sure don't put `{{}}` around the variable.

```
String:  <div ng-bind-html-unsafe="tab.content"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @sza .. for some reason that didn't work
I think ng-bind-html-unsafe is good for non-Angular elements, and Angular Elements need to be "compiled"
<br>

I found a solution here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417607/angular-ng-bind-html-unsafe-and-directive-within-it