# Add <object> with custom attributes using AngularJS controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm attempting to add an `<object></object>`into my html using a controller. When I load a `<div>` or a `<p>`, it works properly, but when I add an `<object>` it doesn't appear, nor do any custom attributes.

HTML:

```
<html ng-app="myAngularSite">        
...
...
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
        <div id="myloader" ng-bind-html="myObject"></div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myAngularSite', ['ngRoute']);

angular.module('myAngularSite', ['ngSanitize'])
        .controller('MyController', ['$scope',function($scope) {
            $scope.myObject = 
                '<object id="my_object" data="mysite.html" width="99.5%" height="400px" style="overflow:auto;border:3px ridge gray"/>';
        }]);
```

How can I add the custom attributes and the object into my site? I noticed that attributes won't appear when I try to load a `<div id"with_attribut></div>` with attributes, although the divs appear by themselves.

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of angular are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 1.2.22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom directive is probably the good solution, you can always add more custom behaviours. With ngBindHtml you will be limited. Here is link which can help you:

[angular ng-bind-html and directive within it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417607/angular-ng-bind-html-unsafe-and-directive-within-it)