# AngularJS directive in ng-bind-html

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In the application I am working on, a service supplies the app with a json, containing HTML. I output the HTML in a template like this:

```
<div ng-bind-html="renderHtml(widget.article.body)"></div>
```

This HTML may contain custom directives, like an inline-chart:

```
directiveModule.directive('inlineChart', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: { inline-widget:'=elem' },
        template: '<p ng-bind="inline-widget.blah"></p>'
    };
});
```

If I use the directive normally in a template, everything works fine, but it seems it is not being touched when used in ng-bing-html with the renderHtml function.

Any suggestions how this could be realised are very much appreciated!

Comment: Have you included [`ngSanitize`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize) module? Where is renderHTml function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import the `ngSanitize` module and use the `$sce` service. It should look something like this:

```
// Remember the following comes from angular-sanitize.js found on the angular website and
// also must be included in the web app.
angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $sce) {
    //... other controller code
    $scope.renderHtml = function(html) {
      return $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
    };
  });
```

In short, the `$sce` service will mark the html as trusted. You can find documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize)

**EDIT:** I realize I may have not answered the question. It seems that you're asking about binding scope variables to the directive that is rendered within your directive? In order to get elements to compile properly, you're going to have to use the `$compile` service and change your logic up a bit. First, the template:

```
<p class="place-directive-here"></p>
```

Then the directive:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('myDirective', function($compile) {
    return {
      scope: {
        inlineWidget: '='
      },
      template: '<p class="place-directive-here"></p>',
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        var placement = elem.find('.place-directive-here');
        scope.$watch('inlineWidget', function(widget){
          if(!widget){
            return;
          }
          // Compile the html against the scope. This will bind the dom to your
          // current scope
          var newElement = $compile(widget.blah)(scope);
          // Place in the view
          placement.html(newElement);
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

You can find the compile documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile). Hopefully this is a more comprehensive answer to what you're looking for.

**EDIT 2:** For clarification, the directive should look like this on the page:

```
<div my-directive inline-widget="someInlineWidget"></div>
```

The `place-directive-here` class is just a handle for the directive to find your `<p>` tag and render inside of it. However, if angular is not concerned with the html that is rendered inside of `my-directive`, the first solution that I provided should work just fine and the template property of `my-directive` should be:

```
template: '<p ng-bind-html="renderHtml(inlineWidget.blah)"></p>'
```

Comment: i don't quite understand what you mean with "place-directive-here". if the directive is called 'myDirective' as in your example, should it be just "my-directive"?

Comment: the problem seems to be, that angular is not looking for custom directives inside the rendered html. the 'link' part of the directive you wrote is never activated :(

Comment: Sorry. The first solution should work then. I added another edit for clarification.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time. Unfortunately this is not the issue I am having. For clarification: The JSON-Feed contains html that is rendered with ng-bind-html="renderHtml(...)". And inside THAT html is a custom directive. But the custom directive is not found, probably because angular is looking for directives before it is rendering the html from the JSON.
Which means that the $watch is not working, since the directive doesn't get instanced.

Comment: That's because the html that `ng-bind-html` produces does not bind to scope variables (and is not parsed as an angular DOM element) which is why it's not picking up your directive. If you want to do that, you're going to have to use `$compile` as I stated in my first edit.

Answer (score 6):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31880192/1345244

Add this directive [angular-bind-html-compile](https://github.com/incuna/angular-bind-html-compile/blob/master/angular-bind-html-compile.js)

```js
.directive('bindHtmlCompile', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(function () {
        return scope.$eval(attrs.bindHtmlCompile);
      }, function (value) {
        // Incase value is a TrustedValueHolderType, sometimes it
        // needs to be explicitly called into a string in order to
        // get the HTML string.
        element.html(value && value.toString());
        // If scope is provided use it, otherwise use parent scope
        var compileScope = scope;
        if (attrs.bindHtmlScope) {
          compileScope = scope.$eval(attrs.bindHtmlScope);
        }
        $compile(element.contents())(compileScope);
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

Use it like this :

```
<div bind-html-compile="data.content"></div>
```

Really easy :)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: Beware that you may compile several ($watch) different html with the same scope. You should create new child scopes and destroy the previous one every time the $watch value changes.

Answer (score 0):

An example of **Angular directive** having attributes with **HTML tags**

View working example over [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/HgT3D4CAzawkPGjN8qRD?p=preview)

This example shows how to create `md-card` within `directive` by passing `title` and `content` and content having anchor tag `<a>`

Use `$sce.trustAsHtml` within `link` as `$sce` works when it is bound to `scope`

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <my-app-card title="Card Title" content="Card Content with anchor <a href='http://www.google.com' target='_blank'> Google </a>"></my-app-card>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",['ngMaterial'])
    .directive ('myAppCard', ['$sce', function($sce){
        return {
            scope:{ title:"@title", content:"@content"},
            link : function(scope, element, attr) {
                var hcont = $sce.trustAsHtml(attr.content);
                var html = "<md-card><md-card-content><h2>"+ attr.title + "</h2><p>"+ hcont +"</p></md-card-content></md-card>";
                scope.$watch('myAppCard', function() {
                      element.append(html);
                    }
                )
            }
        }
}]);
```