# Scope variables settled and loaded from AJAX calls are not being rendered

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to load a form using Angular with the following process :

1. Load values from a PHP script
2. Load the template on which values have to be rendered

**HTML**

```
<form ng-controller="formularCtrl" ng-init="initForm()">
    <div ng-bind-html='form.template | unsafe'></div>
</form>
```

**ANGULAR**

```
angular
    .module('exampleFormular', ['formular.module', 'ngSanitize'])
    .controller('formularCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

        $scope.form = {};

        $scope.initForm = function () {
            $http.get('ajax/loadForm.php')
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.form.content = data;
            })
            .then(function() {
                $http.get('templates/formTemplate.html')
                .success(function (data) {
                   $scope.form.template = data;
                });
            });
        };

    })
    .filter('unsafe', function($sce) { return $sce.trustAsHtml; });
```

**PHP**

```
$form = new StdClass();
$form->name->id = 'name';
$form->name->type = 'text';
$form->name->value = 'Test';
echo json_encode($form);
// {"name": {"id":"name", "type":"text", "value":"Test"}}
```

**TEMPLATE**

```
<input 
  type="{{form.content.name.type}}" 
  id="{{form.content.name.id}}" 
  value="{{form.content.name.value}}" />
```

---

The current result is my HTML being well formed, and my values being settled.

```
console.log($scope.form.content.name.value); // Test
```

But the values are not being rendered in the HTML, resulting on an input with `{{form.content.name.value}}` inside, instead of 'Test'

I'm not comfortable yet with scope things, but I tried to `$scope.$apply()` during the AJAX calls or after, with no success (and absolutly no change).

(I also tried to load the template, **and then** load the values, still not working.)

Comment: Have you tried to [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) the template ?

Comment: Try the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417607/angular-ng-bind-html-unsafe-and-directive-within-it . It's basically what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the Ajax success function, do $scope.$apply(function() { $scope.form.template = data; });

Comment: To avoid the digest error, wrap the $scope.$apply() in a $timeout with 0 delay. This puts the operation in queue once digest is done. You'll need to inject $timeout into the controller. $timeout(function() { $scope.$apply( ... ); }, 0);