# angular sanitize, add exceptions for specific directives

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to add exceptions for angular sanitize to allow custom and core directives?

such as:

```
ng-click
my-custom-directive
```

Comment: what does `ng-click` have to do with angular sanitize? What exceptions are you referring to? Question is pretty vague

Comment: If I include an ng-click in the html to be sanitized it gets removed, I would like that it wouldn't

Comment: Won't do any good since using `ng-bind-html` doesn't get compiled by angular anyway so the directives are useless Suggest you change your approach

Comment: but there is a way to make the code be compiled by angular though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417607/angular-ng-bind-html-unsafe-and-directive-within-it

Answer (score 0):

`angularSnitize` have lists of tags that it ignore. See *237 - 266* lines in `angular-sanitize` directive.