# Unable to read angular function from json

Tags: angularjs, json

**This is my Json:**

```
"review": {

{
"message_bar_text": "Please carefully review your transaction details. To make any changes after confirmation, please call <a ng-click=\"callCSC(number)\">1-800-325-6000</a>.
}

}
```

**Here i am reading json to bind html:**

```
WUAPI.getTranslateContent = function () {

 $timeout(function () {

        $http.get("translate/en_US.json").then(
          function (response) {
            $rootScope.getDefaultLocale = response.data;
          },
          function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          })
      });
    };
```

But i am unable bind ng-click element into HTML. The angular tags are completely removed when i am seeing the Html.

I am using ng-bind-html to read html tags(It's working fine) but i am unable to read angular tags. Please suggest me the solution

Comment: Review your JSON. It has syntax errors.

Comment: Had a typo consider this json {
    "review": {
           "message_bar_text": "Please carefully review your transaction details. To make any changes after confirmation, please call <a ng-click=\"callCSC(number)\">1-800-325-6000</a>.
    }
}

Comment: Still lacking a `"`.

Comment: { "review": { "message_bar_text": "Please carefully review your transaction details. To make any changes after confirmation, please call <a ng-click=\"callCSC(number)\">1-800-325-6000</a>. "} }

Comment: I have validated json it's fine. The issue besides somewhere.

Comment: `ng-bind-html` doesn't compile directives, just raw html

Comment: what we have to use to bind directives

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417607/angular-ng-bind-html-and-directive-within-it

Comment: This link won't be the solution for me.

Answer (score -1):

The asynchronous response of $http.get happens once the scope phase has finished. You wont see the update until the scope updates again.

Try triggering it manually once the http.get returns:

```
$http.get("translate/en_US.json").then(
    function (response) {
        $rootScope.getDefaultLocale = response.data;

        // Trigger a scope update
        if (!$scope.$$phase) 
        {
            $scope.$apply($rootScope.getDefaultLocale); 
        }
  },
  function (error) { console.log(error); });
```

Comment: I tested it still i am not able to get ng-click.

Comment: angular already does this internally. Answer has factually incorrect statements

Comment: any solution for this @charlietfl