# How to parse scope name in interpolate?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have code like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, category) in shop.categories">
  <div ng-repeat="(key, group) in category.groups">
    <span ng-bind="'groupPrice-' + ($parent.$index + 1) + '-' + ($index + 1)"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to display in `<span>` value of example `$scope.groupPrice-1-1`, `$scope.groupPrice-1-2` etc.

How can I parse my `ng-bind` to display value of scope? Now this display name of scope, not value.

Comment: What about using expression?

Answer (score 2):

Try the angular directive for eval your string to object properties.

The html code:

```html
<div ng-app="vkApp">
    <div ng-controller="vkController">        
        <span compile="groupPrice_1_1"></span>
        <br>
        <span compile="groupPrice_1_2"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The angular script:

```js
angular.module('vkApp', []);

angular.module('vkApp')
  .controller('vkController', ['$scope', '$compile', function ($scope, $compile) {
      $scope.groupPrice_1_1 = "Hi man !";
      $scope.groupPrice_1_2 = "lol !";
  }]);

  // declare a new module, and inject the $compileProvider
angular.module('vkApp')
  .directive('compile', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
      return function(scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.$watch(
            function(scope) {
               // watch the 'compile' expression for changes
              return scope.$eval(attrs.compile);
            },
            function(value) {
              // when the 'compile' expression changes
              // assign it into the current DOM
              element.html(value);

              // compile the new DOM and link it to the current
              // scope.
              // NOTE: we only compile .childNodes so that
              // we don't get into infinite loop compiling ourselves
              $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            }
        );
    };
}]);
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/m59d1bbs/4/)

Cr. [angular ng-bind-html and directive within it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417607/angular-ng-bind-html-and-directive-within-it)

Note: you must change `$scope.groupPrice-1-1` to `$scope.groupPrice_1_1` instead.

Hope this tip may be help.

Comment: Code from JSFiddle should be posted on the answer and not only on JSFiddle.

Comment: @Mistalis So sorry, i have no more time sir. Let me change it.  :)

Comment: No problem, +1! :)