# Angular directive is not working if pass with html string and parse with ng-bind-html

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I am creating a simple angular directive for reference. When I add it to the HTML page it is working fine but when I add it through HTML tags string and parse with ng-bind-html then it is not working. Please suggest some approach.

**Directive**:

```
<notification message="{{message}}"></notification>

//When pass through controller object, It's not working
$scope.htmlContent = '<p>Hello</p><notification message="{{message}}"></notification>';
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GkjGJGgYS8My68cWwrsK?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call a compile directive to achieve this functionality

JS Code

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap',]);

app.filter('to_trusted', ['$sce', function($sce){
        return function(text) {
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
        };
    }]);

    app.controller("MessageCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Product created!";
     $scope.htmlContent = '<notification message="{{message}}"></notification>';

})
app.directive("notification", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            message: '@'
        },
        template: '<div class="alert">{{message}}</div>'
    }
});

app.directive('compile', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
      return function(scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.$watch(
            function(scope) {
               // watch the 'compile' expression for changes
              return scope.$eval(attrs.compile);
            },
            function(value) {
              // when the 'compile' expression changes
              // assign it into the current DOM
              element.html(value);

              // compile the new DOM and link it to the current
              // scope.
              // NOTE: we only compile .childNodes so that
              // we don't get into infinite loop compiling ourselves
              $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            }
        );
    };
}]);
```

HTML code

```
<div ng-controller="MessageCtrl">
   <div compile="htmlContent"></div>
   <notification message="{{message}}"></notification>
</div>
```

Check [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9V7bdww79LyGbkKIec9i?p=preview)

You can read more about this in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417607/angular-ng-bind-html-and-directive-within-it)