# Ionic: Click event is not intercepting

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have this directive to intercept link click:

```
var app = angular.module('mobApp.services');
app.directive('a', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E', // only Elements (<a>),
        link: function(scope, elm, attr) {
            elm.on('click', function($event) {
                $event.preventDefault()
                var href = attr.href;
                if(!!href && href !== '#') {
                    window.open(href, '_system', 'location=yes');
                }
                return false
            })
        }
    }
})
```

I have this element

```
<p ng-bind-html="post.details | linky:'_blank'" class="ng-binding">
   <a target="_blank" href="https://davidwalsh.name/speech-recognition" class="">
        https://davidwalsh.name/speech-recognition
   </a>
</p>
```

clicking on `a` is not firing the above directive code.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because the html markup that you render via `ng-bind-html` has not been compiled by Angular in order to directives could work. So if you want to add directive to the document dynamically, you have to [compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler) it. Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417607/angular-ng-bind-html-and-directive-within-it) of how you can do that.

Comment: how can i use `compile` directive with `ng-bind-html`?

Comment: You can't. Create a wrapper directive/component or controller, inside of which you will compile and append compiled html into existing DOM node via `html()` or `append()` method.

Comment: can you give example how to do that