# Dynamically add AngularJS Directive to page to display and render the directive not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

If I type onto page

```
<liberty-directive></liberty-directive>
```

That works fine.

However, I have database table with list of directive names.

So

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="lib in vm.liberty">
        <td>{{lib.Tag}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So this is the object with the directive tag

```
{{lib.Tag}}  = <td class="ng-binding">&lt;liberty-directive&gt;&lt;/liberty-directive&gt;</td>
```

Viewing source it "looks fine"  , but copy and paste to this it is changing,  how to prevent that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get it work, you have to compile your html in each iteration of `ng-repeat` (use [`$compile`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)). For that, you can use a simple custom directive: ([PLUNKER DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ck0koLfjMvgTpJnX9BRe?p=preview))

```
.directive('compileHtml', ['$compile', function($compile) {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.html(attrs.compileHtml);
    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
  };
}]);
```

Then in your **HTML** use it like:

```
<tr ng-repeat="d in vm.data">
  <td compile-html="{{d.htmlContent}}"></td>
</tr>
```

Controller:

```
function myCtrl() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.data = [
        { "htmlContent": "<my-custom-directive></my-custom-directive>" }, 
        { "htmlContent": "<div>Custom: <span my-attr-directive></span></div>" },
        //... more items
    ];
}
```

---

Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417607/angular-ng-bind-html-and-directive-within-it) if you want more examples.