# Angular $compile doesn't work for rootScope functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function defined in my root scope:

```
app.run(
    function($rootScope, $location) {
        // ...

        $rootScope.goToPage = function(view) {
            $location.path("/" + view);
            console.log("go('"+view+"')");
        }

        // ...
    }
);
```

I use it like that in my views:

```
<a href="" ng-click="goToPage('myPage')">My page</a>
```

It works.

Now, I'm loading some html parts from a REST service, and I need to compile them in order to execute angular code and directives.

This is the directive which compiles them:

```
app.directive('initBind', function($compile, $rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link : function (scope, element, attr) {
            attr.$observe('ngBindHtml',function(){
                if(attr.ngBindHtml){
                    $compile(element[0].children)(scope);
                }
            })
        }
    };
})
```

And I use it like that:

```
<div ng-bind-html="htmlToBind" init-bind>
</div>
```

Note: `htmlToBind` has been pre-processed by `$sce.trustAsHtml`.

Directives inside `htmlToBind` work, but if I place an `a` tag with `ng-click="goToPage('anotherPage')"` it doesn't work. I mean, the page gets refreshed instead of executing the function, and nothing is logged to the console.

It seems that `goToPage` isn't defined in the `$compile` scope, but I also tried passing `$rootScope`(which has the function for sure) without success.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417607/angular-ng-bind-html-and-directive-within-it)? Looks like you can use the suggested custom directive to compile your html without the need for `$sce.trustAsHtml`.