# AngularJS 1.5 bind and compile html to modal

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-1.5

Pretty new to AngularJS and I feel like I've hit something I don't quite understand.  I have a AngularJS component that is opened by a UI-Boostrap modal.  The modal body can contain a nearly infinite number of forms that the user may need/want to fill out.

I've looking at other plunkers/posts/AngularJS styleguide trying to figure out what the correct process here is.

1. I resolve some valid but untrusted HTML which contains the form (some inputs/textareas/labels/datepickers/etc...).  These elements have 'ng-model="$ctrl.modalData.bindings." inside of them.  I supply the bindings to the modalData object that is resolved.
2. I use $sce to elevate(?) the HTML to be trusted(?). I can get the forms to display correctly using just this, but I can't data-bind to them without using $compile (I think).
3. I try unsuccessfully to compile the html.  I understand what I've provided is wrong.  Tried multiple ways with no success.

The HTML doesn't just need to be compiled on init, it changes through another method I haven't defined here.  If I can get the $ctrl.$init() code working I can get the rest working.

```
    angular.module('cfv')
    .component('myModal', {
        templateUrl: '../IssueModal.template.html', 
        bindings: {
            modalInstance: "<",
            resolve: "<"
        },
        controller: [                
            '$sce',
            '$compile',
            'formRenderingService',
            function($sce, $compile, formRenderingService: FormRenderingService) {
                var $ctrl = this;

                $ctrl.$init = () => {

                    $ctrl.width = 800;
                    $ctrl.modalData = $ctrl.resolve.modalData;

                    $ctrl.formHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml($ctrl.modalData.formHtml);

                    $compile($ctrl.formHtml);                        

                    let $modalContent = angular.element(document).find('.modal-content');
                    $modalContent[0].style.width = $ctrl.width + 30 + 'px'; // TODO: Can't find a better way to access the content border for dynamic sizing...
                }

                $ctrl.handleClose = () => {
                    $ctrl.modalInstance.close($ctrl.selectedSource);
                };

                $ctrl.handleDismiss = () => {
                    $ctrl.modalInstance.dismiss("cancel");
                };                  

                $ctrl.$init();
        }]
    });
```

Template:

```
<div class="modal-body" style="border: thin; border-color: lightgrey; border-left: none; width: 70%; padding: 0;">
    <div style="height: 465px; width: 100.2%; border: none; border-bottom:solid; border-bottom-color:lightgrey; border-bottom-width:thin;">
        <h3 class="bwc-text-title" style="margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom: 10px; display:inline-block">Issue Details</h3>
        <button class="bwc-buttons-hollow" type="button" style="border: none; font-weight: 600; font-size:18px; position: absolute; right: 12px; top: 12px;" ng-click="$ctrl.handleDismiss()">X</button>
        <div ng-bind-html="$ctrl.formHtml" style="padding-left: 10px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 15px; right: 15px">
        <button class="bwc-buttons-hollow" type="button" style="margin-right: 10px" ng-click="$ctrl.handleClose()">Edit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NWZZE/6/

From this SO post: [angular ng-bind-html and directive within it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417607/angular-ng-bind-html-and-directive-within-it)

Also of note is the non-standard directive:  https://github.com/incuna/angular-bind-html-compile/blob/master/angular-bind-html-compile.js

After reading up more and honing my search, I implemented this directive in my module and used it almost exactly like the Fiddle.  Works perfectly...just remember to remove the call to `$sce.trustAsHtml`.