# Trigger events in HTML rendered with ng-bind-html

Tags: angularjs

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/AZ6ieHYaURv9GhATNLYt?p=preview) I have an HTML table in a variable. I render the table with `ng-bind-html` and that works fine. The problem is that I cannot trigger events when cells are clicked. For example, `ng-click` at the cell level doesn't call functions declared in AngularJS. How to capture the clicks?

HTML

```
<div ng-bind-html="html"></div>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctl', function ($scope,$sce) {

          var htmlTable = `
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td ng-click="clicked()">
                        $39,431.67
                    </td>
                    <td ng-click="clicked()">
                        $14,861.50
                    </td>
                    <td ng-click="clicked()">
                        $7,848.97
                    </td>
                    <td ng-click="clicked()">
                        $16,721.20
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </table> `;

        $scope.html = $sce.trustAsHtml(htmlTable);

    $scope.clicked = function(){
         alert("cell was clicked"); 
    };   
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a **[`directive with compile`](https://github.com/incuna/angular-bind-html-compile/blob/master/angular-bind-html-compile.js)** to do the job, take a look at this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417607/angular-ng-bind-html-and-directive-within-it)**

```
.directive('compile', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(
            function(scope) {
                // watch the 'compile' expression for changes
                return scope.$eval(attrs.compile);
            },
            function(value) {
                // when the 'compile' expression changes
                // assign it into the current DOM
                element.html(value);

                // compile the new DOM and link it to the current
                // scope.
                // NOTE: we only compile .childNodes so that
                // we don't get into infinite loop compiling ourselves
                $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            }
        );
    };
```