# How to make a table sort-able while the whole components is passed as string via ng-bind-html in AngluarJS

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind-html, sorttable.js

Hi I have a situation in AngluarJS that the HTML is generated by back-end and the only thing that front-end should do is to put the HTML which is mostly table tags into the `ng-bind-html` and show it to the user. But now these tables should be sort-able too. How can I do it?

The thing that I've already done is to create my own directive using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417607/angular-ng-bind-html-and-directive-within-it) so make the static string HTML take some actions too. But having them sorted is something else. In other word I want to make my fully generated table with all `<tr>` and `<td>` to get sorted by my actions.

Here is my simplified code (`compile` is my directive):

```
JS:
// The string is fully generated by back-end
$scope.data.html = 
'<table> <tr> <th ng-click="sortByHeader($event)"> Name </th> 
              <th ng-click="sortByHeader($event)"> Age </th> </tr>
              <tr> <td> Sara </td> <td> 15 </td> </tr>
              <tr> <td> David </td> <td> 20 </td> </tr>'

HTML: 
<div compile="data.html"></div>
```

The `ng-click="sortByHeader($event)` is something that back-end can prepare for me so I can use it thanks to the `compile` I wrote that let me find out which header has been clicked. Other than that there is nothing I can do. Unless you can help me :D

Thanks in advance, I hope my question was clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged your question with `sorttable.js` I'm going to assume that you are using that script to sort your tables.
Now, if I understand it correctly, `sorttable.js` parses your HTML for any tables with the class `sortable`. Your table is apparently loaded dynamically, therefore `sorttable.js` does not know about it when it parses the HTML.

But you can tell it to make a dynamically added table sortable, too.

Relevant part taken from the following page:
https://kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/#ajaxtables

> **Sorting a table added after page load**
>
> Once you've added a new table to the page at runtime (for example, by
>   doing an Ajax request to get the content, or by dynamically creating
>   it with JavaScript), get a reference to it (possibly with var
>   newTableObject = document.getElementById(idOfTheTableIJustAdded) or
>   similar), then do this:
>
> sorttable.makeSortable(newTableObject);

You should be able to do that with angular. If not, I can try to put something together later.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Actually it's funny that I tagged `sorttable.js` because I didn't notice `js` and I tagged it as a general subject. But now I looked at the library and saw it can be a solution for my situation, but as I'm no experienced in AngularJS I don't know how to include this library (which is only a js file) in my project.The instruction says you should simply put it in a <script> tag but I don't have <html> and <head> tags in my modules. Is there way to include it with directives and pass the relative address of file like `../sorttable.js` as src?

Comment: @ErfanSamieyan Side note: You stated in your comment to the other answer that your goal is to reduce the work on the client. May I suggest that unless you have a very good reason to return preformatted HTML by your server, it may be better to return pure data and then use `ng-repeat` to populate the table in your front-end. It will allow you to use other popular directives for tables and have a better decoupling of client and server. ---- Now, regarding your question: You need to add the script with a normal `<script>`-tag in your index.html where you also have the reference to angular.js.

Comment: I 100% agree with you about rendering the Table dynamically in front-end, but the case that I'm working has a old structure which they don't to change it. So I should deal with it in front-end. However I should either use this `sorttable.js` file or [jQuery Datatables](https://datatables.net/) which are both seems to be a working solution. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Is the answer to the question "*Does the rendered table have to exactly match the HTML retrieved by the backend?*" a kind of "*No*"?

If that's the case, then here's a hacky way of gaining control of the table contents by parsing and capturing stuff from the backend HTML string using regular expressions.

For example: grab all row data and apply sorting client side

```
// Variables to be set by your sortByHeader functions in order to do client-side sorting
$scope.expression = null;
$scope.direction = null;

var regexToGetTableHead = /<table>\s*(.*<\/th>\s*<\/tr>)/g;
$scope.tableHead = regexToGetTableHead.exec($scope.data.html);

$scope.tableRows = [];

var regexToGetRowContents = /<tr>\s*<td>\s*(\w*)\s*<\/td>\s*<td>\s*(\w*)\s*<\/td>\s*<\/tr>/g;

var match;
while ((match = regexToGetRowContents.exec($scope.data.html)) != null) {
    $scope.tableRows.push({
        "name": match[1],
        "age": match[2] 
    });
}
```

And HTML

```
<table>
    <thead compile="tableHead"></thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in tableRows | orderBy: expression : direction">
            <td>{{row.name}}</td>
            <td>{{row.age}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks this is actually a way but the whole point of the HTML being generated is to reduce the job of front-end but now again parsing the data from it and reusing it doesn't seem to be the best idea.

Comment: I see @ErfanSamieyan; I was treating this more as a limitation from whatever backend system as opposed to a preferred design decision. (I'm not a fan of server-side HTML unless really necessary) I guess what you're after then is to have the `sortByHeader` function defined by the backend, which when clicked would reload the table contents with newly sorted table HTML from the backend.