# ui-sref not working properly when anchor tag is loaded from properties file

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

Entry in properties file

```
MYKEY= <a ui-sref="mystate.state">Go to my page using state</a> and <a href="/#/mypage/page">Go to my page using link/a>
```

I have fetched this key from properties file & applied `$sce.trustAsHtml()` on it and used in html. I could see link for ***Go to my page using link*** but ***Go to my page using state*** not working properly as it has `ui-sref` tag. Can someone please specify reason why it's not working and solution for this.

Note : `ui-sref` is working properly in my project when it's directly used in html.

Comment: In what way did you bind it in to your view? like this only `<div> {{ test_model }} </div>`?

Comment: Yes, I did the same

Comment: you should use `$compile` then apply the `$sce.trustAsHtml()`

Comment: No, only compile needed for it. $sce.trustAsHtml() after $compile may land into issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be because the content is not compiled, hence `ui-sref` is not working.

I found the below directive which compiles and inserts html code, please check if this solves your issue!

The Directive was got from this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417607/angular-ng-bind-html-and-directive-within-it)

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope) {
  $scope.test = function() {
    console.log("it works!");
  }
  $scope.html = '<a ui-sref="mystate.state">Go to my page using state</a> and <a href="/#/mypage/page">Go to my page using link</a><button ng-click="test()">click</button>{{asdf}}';
});

app.directive('compile', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(
            function(scope) {
                // watch the 'compile' expression for changes
                return scope.$eval(attrs.compile);
            },
            function(value) {
                // when the 'compile' expression changes
                // assign it into the current DOM
                element.html(value);
                // compile the new DOM and link it to the current
                // scope.
                // NOTE: we only compile .childNodes so that
                // we don't get into infinite loop compiling ourselves
                $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            }
        );
    };
}])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller='MyController' ng-app="myApp">
  <div compile="html"></div>
</div>
```