# Why does not work ng-click from AJAX?

Tags: angularjs

I get HTML from AJAX and put it on page.
This HTML has `ng-click` event, that does not work. Only after reload page.
What is way does exist to resolve it?

Comment: Could you paste link relevant code and/or link to plunker ?

Comment: All simple. There is HTML `<div ng-click="Do()"></div>` that are returned from AJAX request in page.

Comment: How does the HTML end up on the page after a reload if it needs an AJAX request the first time?

Comment: if you insert that as html have to use `$compile`

Comment: here's an SO discussion question/answer on [$compile and dynamic data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157305/angularjs-compiling-dynamic-html-strings-from-database) that may be of help.

Comment: Can you share one exmaple with `$compile`?

Comment: searching on SO is easy, just type something like `[angularjs] $compile ajax` (in the searchbox at the top of this page) and you will get some relevant posts. It is worthwhile to give something a try and post your code to SO for further questions/critique etc. Anyhow, for another example use of `$compile` you can also reference `@Chandermani's` approach here: [example of the usage of $compile in a Directive to load a data feed from Twitter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17344875/4245493) GL!